# solr index java source files as text

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to upload lots of source files (say, `java`) to `solr` to allow indexed search on them.
They should be posted as **plain text files**.

No special parsing is required.
When trying to upload one java file I get "Unknown Source" related error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/uwyn/jhighlight/renderer/XhtmlRendererFactory
```

When I rename the file adding `.txt` in the end, it is uploaded successfully.

I have thousands of files to upload on a daily basis and need to keep original names.
How do I tell solr to treat all files in the directory as `.txt`?
Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For googlers, concerning the Solr error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/uwyn/jhighlight/renderer/XhtmlRendererFactory
```

You can correct this by adding the jar "jhighlight-1.0.jar" in Solr. To do so:

- Download the old [solr 4.9](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.9.0/). In recent version, jhighlight is not present.
- Extract solr-4.9.0\contrib\extraction\lib\jhighlight-1.0.jar
- Copy jhighlight-1.0.jar to the solr installation under solr/server/lib/ext/
- Restart the server.

Comment: This helped. Downloaded the jar from maven - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uwyn/jhighlight/1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by integrating solr with tika.

Apache will help you to extract the text of the source files.

It has a source code parser which supports c,c++ and Java.

Here is the link which will give you more details.
https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://tika.apache.org/1.12/formats.html&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=972&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1461564865&sig=APY536wBFFAcFH7yUyvhh2TFslPz6LeClA